# Save data from multiple tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs

I have an app that has 4 to 5 tabs. Each tab has specific information to be filled by the user. I want to save the data from all these tabs when user chooses the save option from the menu.

What would be the best way (if not best at least the most reliable one !) to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to duplicate the Save button on each tab, I feel this is the best decision from the user experience point of view: by the time you get to the tab where a single Save button is, you can forget what's on the other tabs and also saving something that's not visible to you at the moment is not quite convenient. Just let the user Save the data on each tab. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to implement the save using the menu option. When user presses menu he gets option to save and when he selects it, the complete information is saved